# Mutex analog in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, concurrency, mutex

I have multiple threads, executing similar queries. They shouldn't be executed the same time. I can create and check mutex for this purpose from ADO.Net client, but for some reason I'd prefer to do this using SQL. Is it possible?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. [Application Locks (or Mutexes) in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

Use the locking available in SQL Server:

[Introduction to Locking in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server)