# Is there an equivalent of mutex or critical section for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, mutex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mutex analog in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596377/mutex-analog-in-sql)

We have a large ASP.NET web service that relies on the heavy use of SQL Server 2008 database. Lately I started seeing the following messages in the log:

> Error 1205 : Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

I know multithreaded programming really well and understand what deadlocks are. In a multi-threaded C++ or C# code, I would use `mutex` or a `critical section` to isolate a mutually exclusive part of the code to prevent deadlocks.

So I'm wondering if SQL Server has the same mutex mechanism?

To clarify, I have a lot of complex statements, stuff like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
'doing other SQL selects, updates, etc.
COMMIT
```

so what I am looking for is this:

```
'ENTER CRITICAL SECTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION
'doing other SQL selects, updates, etc.
COMMIT
'LEAVE CRITICAL SECTION
```

With this approach I'm looking for an easy solution that doesn't involve a heavy re-write of the tested-and-proven SQL logic.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But do I need stored procedures to use it?

Comment: @user843732 No. Just call `sp_getapplock` from inside your transaction. Makes no difference if your code is in an SP or not.